# DAX Formula for COUNT Ignoring Column Filters but Respecting Row Filters and Slicers

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

I need a DAX formula to count rows respecting all slicers and the rows in question only.
The example below shows the source data (top) and the expected result (bottom), which is filtered to 2022 by a slicer.
Surely this is possible, but I've been trying for a day and am out of ideas.

[DAX Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnjgu.png)

I have tried using ALL, ALLEXCEPT, and KEEPFILTERS in CALCULATE, but can't seem to get it to work the way I expect.  The closest I have come is with this:
CALCULATE(COUNT([ROW_ELEMENT]), ALLEXCEPT(Table1, Table1[ROW_ELEMENT]))
But this produces nulls for names that don't appear in the data set for each gender, and ignores the year filter.
[Best Effort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDQEN.png)

[This is fine if I can just get the year slicer to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AECYG.png)

Comment: That's not how DAX works. You can remove filters from columns or tables, but not from columns in a visual. (You'd have to refer to the column names in the table).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/removefilters-function-dax

Comment: @user3638472 did REMOVEFILTERS (Table1[ROW_ELEMENT]) solve it for you? If you don’t mind, what is your use case? I mean referring to your first pic, in the matrix with the genders vs names, it might be confusing to find a value (e.g. the total by gender) where there is no “intersection” between the gender and the name. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the link on REMOVEFILTERS.  I forgot to mention - this is in Excel and REMOVEFILTERS is not yet supported.

The nulls don't really matter.  The bigger issue is the slicers.  The above is almost exactly what I need.  If I can just get it to respect the year filter, I'm good.  Surely there is a way to do this.

Comment: Oh, I am not familiar with the limitations/specifics of DAX in Excel. So ALL (Table1[ROW_ELEMENT]) does not work as expected either?

Comment: @Anonymous - I think you are asking if I tried =CALCULATE(COUNT([gender]), ALL(Table2[gender])).  If so, yes, and it has the effect of separating results again.  Only ALLEXCEPT comes close.

Ultimately I want to make a measure that calculates what percent of the janes are male and female.  In the real data the row values have overlap, so they won't sum to 100%.  Imagine, if it helps, that the rows are ingredients like eggs, wheat, and flour, the columns are different types of food like deserts, main course, and snacks, and the values in each column being quantified are recipes.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t pay enough attention: You should try ALL(table[head of the column with the names]) … not the row elements but column elements, i.e. to consider all names and just to apply the filters for gender and year. Good luck! Edit: =CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table2), ALL(Table2[names]))

Comment: Note: ALL(Table2[gender]) would overwrite the “filter context” given by the rows of gender, i.e. for one name column, you will get the same (total) value regardless the different rows of gender … ALL(Table2[names]) works in the same way but related to the names, i.e. it will not differentiate by names.

Comment: Ohhhh you are amazing!  Thanks you sooooo much!

Comment: From your answer, I assume it worked out? Cheers! P.S. countrows () is the preferred way instead of count (..) when applicable, but both will give you the same result here.

Comment: Thanks again!  That would make sense indeed.  Thanks for helping me get unstuck.  I think I can't close the question unless there is an "Answer" submitted.  Can I ask you to paste your solution as an answer?